# Characters not returning

Tags: c#

How to fix the errors with characters in C# Employee class I am making.  I know how to handle string, int, and double. The char.Parse doesn't cooperate.

```
   public static string AskForLastName()
   {
       string inValue;
       Console.Write("Enter last name: ");
       inValue = Console.ReadLine();
       return  inValue; //works fine
   }

    public static char AskForGender()
   {
       char inValue;
       Console.Write("Enter gender: ");
       inValue = Console.ReadLine();//error here for some reason
       return (char.Parse(inValue));//error here for some reason
   }

    public static int AskForNoDependendents()
    {
        string inValue;
        Console.Write("Enter the dependents: ");
        inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        return (int.Parse(inValue));//works fine
    }

    public static double AskForAnnualSalary()
    {
        string inValue;
        Console.Write("Enter annual salary: ");
        inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        return (double.Parse(inValue));//works fine
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message what you get?

Comment: "error here" isn't exactly descriptive - what's happening?

Comment: Try `readkey` (readline can take more than 1 character - it returns a string).

Comment: -1 for not being a specific question.

Comment: Sorry, Visual Studio 2010shows a blus line under the return (char.Parse(inValue));

Comment: It also says invlaid arguements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

Console.ReadLine returns a string. You can use `string[]` to get the first character of your string. But you have to make sure that the user inserts at least one character.

#### Sample

```
public static char AskForGender()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter gender (m/w): ");
        string inValue = Console.ReadLine(); 
        // check that the user inputs a character
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inValue) && (inValue[0] == 'm' || inValue[0] == 'w'))
            return inValue[0]; 
    }
}
```

### Update

My sample covers now that the user inputs `m` or `w`.

### Update

It is homework so...

If your Teacher ask "But what happens if the user inputs a `M` instead of `m`? You should say "It asks the user again".

If your Teacher asks then "How to make it possible to accept `M` and `m`? You should say i can make it case insensitive.

#### Sample

You should use i can use .NET's `.ToUpper()` method.

> .ToUpper() - Returns a copy of this string converted to uppercase.

```
public static char AskForGender()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter gender (m/w): ");
        string inValue = Console.ReadLine(); 
        // check that the user inputs a character
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inValue) && (inValue.ToUpper()[0] == 'M' || inValue.ToUpper()[0] == 'W'))
            return inValue.ToUpper()[0]; // returns M or W
    }
}
```

Comment: @ChrisShain the `while` loop prompts the user for another entry until an `m` or `w` is entered...

Comment: I don't know arrays yet, but the selection in the loop is very clear to me at my level.

Comment: @badboy If you do MyString[0] it will return the first character in the string.

Answer (score 3):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string.  You can't implicitly convert that to a character- what if someone enters "Male" or "   M" (preceded by one or more spaces).

Your `AskForGender` method is going to need to be smarter about what input it accepts, and how it parses that input.

If you really need a character out of this (to satisfy the assignment, or whatever), then you need to figure out a way to get from all of the possible `String` inputs ("Male", "MALE", "Female", "Horse", "Dog", "4", etc.) to either:

- An acceptable `Character` (presumably 'M' or 'F', but maybe others?)

or

- An error condition, whereupon maybe you print a nice error message and ask them to re-enter?

Comment: Should I add regex validation for characters. I was planning to add validation after the foundation is set. I am still a student.

Comment: And as such I've tagged this question as homework.  I intentionally didn't tell you *how* to make it smarter, but I will say that regex sounds like a reasonable approach.  Try it, and if you run into trouble you know where to ask for help.

Comment: I appreciate it, I prefer to just get a knudge in the right direction instead of a spoon feeding as I am learning this for my future career. Thank you! I will tag homework instead of C# next time. I didn't know homework was a tag selection.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pull a `string` into a `char`.  `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`.

If you need specifically one character (Presumably M or F) consider making your `inValue` a `string`, trimming it (to ensure there are no leading spaces), and then returning `inValue[0]` (which should be a char)

Something like:

```
string inValue = Console.ReadLine();
inValue = inValue.Trim();
return inValue[0];
```

**Note- that's not the best way to do it, but it should make the idea fairly clear.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) `ReadLine` returns a `string` - you can't assign a string to a `char`!